# Excessive Invocation of Copy Constructor for Custom Comparator Class in C++ Priority Queue

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue, copy-constructor

I had declared a `priority_queue` with custom comparator having a vector property in it. Below is the full code for it:

**CODE**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Compare
{
private:
    vector<int> vec;

public:
    Compare(const vector<int> &vec) { this->vec = vec; }

    Compare(const Compare &obj)
    {
        this->vec = obj.vec;
        cout << "Copy Constructor Called!\n";
    }

    bool operator()(const int &left, const int &right)
    {
        return vec[left] > vec[right];
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, Compare> pq{Compare(vec)};

    cout << "Pushing 1\n";
    pq.push(1);
    cout << "Pushed 1\n";
    cout << "Pushing 2\n";
    pq.push(2);
    cout << "Pushed 2\n";

    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        cout << "Popped = " << pq.top() << '\n';
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is strange!!

**OUTPUT**

```
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Pushing 1
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Pushed 1
Pushing 2
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Pushed 2
Popped = 1
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Copy Constructor Called!
Popped = 2
Copy Constructor Called!
```

Why the copy constructor is called so many times, for every push and pop operation?

Also without any push or pop operation, when I just declared the `priority_queue`, the copy constructor is called **4 times**

Why is this occurring? Isn't it correct that the priority_queue stores the comparator class object and utilizes it whenever comparisons are needed?

Comment: You should print the value of `this`, not just "Copy Constructor Called!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::make_heap` takes the comparator by value [see](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), and so do numerous internal functions in the `libstdc++` implementation of `make_heap`. `libc++` does [less](https://godbolt.org/z/6eTM3q6hr) passing by value, but it does some.

Comparators are supposed to be cheap to copy. If they need external data, make them store a pointer to external data.